# print information to page using yml data file using Middleman / ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, erb, middleman

Given a data file containing a title, age, and description tag how would I go about printing these out individually? I've tried just using a simple;

```
<% data.folder.to.file.EXAMPLE.title %>
```

and I get a blank where it should be, with no error.

Whereas using a loop on a list defined in the same data file works just fine;

```
<% data.folder.to.file.EXAMPLE.list.each do |l| %>
    <li>
        <%= f %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I guess I could just put everything into a list, but I want to know how to better use these data files with my middleman setup. My aim is to be able to create static pages via middleman's proxy to generate pages that end up using the data in yml files of the same name. I'm halfway there I think - taking the looping example I just add [proxyname] after EXAMPLE and it selects the correct yml file.

Help and pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forget what I said, I don't know why it didn't work before and now suddenly does - but that's what I'm currently faced with. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

In your example where you used `<% data.folder.to.file.EXAMPLE.title %>` this will just evaluate the expression but not print it out.

Instead using `<%=` will print out the expression to the output file e.g. `<%= data.folder.to.file.EXAMPLE.title %>`